# Touch event is not working in scrollview

Tags: android

In this code touch event (left to right and right to left) is not working. If I remove ScrollView and replace RelativeLayout to LinearLayout then touch event is working. And all the widget are overlapped together. Please solve my problem as soon as possible.

Touch event (Right to left and left to right) is not working in scrollview using in xml file. How to manage both scrollview with touch event. The hnextpage.xml page is.

Please tell me sir, how we can manage it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           <TextView    
                android:id="@+id/marquee_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:freezesText="true"

                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_dark" />


      <!-- Name Label -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/name_label"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

      <!-- Description Label -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/description_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marquee_txt"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textColor="#dc6800"/>

       <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/du_logo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/description_label"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


      <!-- Price Label 

                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
      -->
      <TextView android:id="@+id/date_label"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/name_label"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textSize="18sp"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
                  />
          </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you want to get an effect of horizontal and vertical scroll in time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ScrollView layout height from match_parent to wrap_content:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

It worked earlier: [Android ScrollView not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924096/android-scrollview-not-working-properly#answer-19924556)

Comment: In this code touch event (left to right and right to left) is not working. If I remove ScrollView and replace RelativeLayout to LinearLayout then touch event is working. And all the widget are overlapped together. Please solve my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: In this code, Touch event is not working. Please solve my problem sir.