# making Multiple EditText's scroll inside scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, scrollview

I am trying to make the edittext's scroll in case the view doesn't them all. The user should be able to scroll the edittexts when keyboard is on or off.

I have tried multiple combinations of `linearLayout` and `ScrollView` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone please check what is wrong with it?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Details"
            android:textColor="#EB8024"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="URI"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip_addr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="IP Address"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/port"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Port"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Application Name"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/string"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_textfield_activated_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Nick Names"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/theme_btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light"
            android:onClick="onClickNext"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#EB8024"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is happening when u try with your code??

Comment: @Lal It starts normally but doesn't scrolls at all

Comment: Have you tried `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: can you please try to set this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" properties in your AndroidManiFest.xml under <activity tag.

Comment: also try removing the height and width attribute..

Comment: @Haresh sry, its not working

Comment: Have you checked what u've said @Raj ?

Answer (score -1):

Make your `ScrollView` fill the viewport and match parent's height instead of wrapping content.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: done. not working. No errors reported but scroll also not working

Comment: That doesn't work..Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924096/android-scrollview-not-working-properly)

Comment: @Lal it works for me. Sorry it's not helping you, Raj.