# I would like to add vertical scroll view in alert dialog because i have many widgets in my layout, where they cant be shown in one screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I had used

```
<ScrollView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

in my `scrollview`, but scrolling is not working. Please help me!!

Comment: Give more info about your implementation, please.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ScrollView not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924096/android-scrollview-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:fillViewport="true"` in scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```